# Suggestion for datatype in Python

Tags: python

I have started working with time series data with the first column being datetime of format (e.g. 12/01/2015 05:01:34) and second column being some value like temperature. i.e. my data is 2D and first column is time and second being some variable.

What is the suggested datatype I should use ? I intend to use the first column (date time) as index for all activities.

Comment: You sound confused. You sound like you're asking about a "data type" but you used the word "data base" (two words?) which sounds to me like you either wanted "data type" (two words) or "database" (one word).   A database is a program that stores your data. A data type is something like a list or an array in memory in python. Be more clear please.

Answer (score 2):

you can start by using a dictionary which will allow you to use the key in order to obtain its value:

dictionary = { 'time' : 'temperature' }

here is a small tutorial on using dictionaries
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm

Example:

```
dictionary = {'12/01/2015 05:01:34': '39C', '12/02/2015 05:01:34':'28C': 'First'}

dictionary ['12/01/2015 05:01:34'] = 40C; # update existing entry
dictionary ['12/03/2015 05:01:34'] = "30C"; # Add new entry
```

Comment: Dictionaries are a terrible way to hold time series values because they lose their ORDERING. If there are thousands or millions of values, y ou'd have to extract a list of keys, and then SORT them.    There is an Ordered Dictionary type in python that sounds like a good idea for time series values, but it might be horribly slow or wasteful of memory anyways.

Comment: which is why i suggested "for starters" but yes, i agree with what you say. anyways, there are so many possibilities, an actual DB can be used but i really dont want to write an essay on this topic

Answer (score 0):

Please, take a look at https://influxdata.com/ it may help you.